# How to nest promises (Promise.all inside Promise.all)

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Consider the following structure of nested `Promises`:

```js
const getData = async() => {

  const refs = [{
      name: "John33",
      age: 33
    },
    {
      name: "John34",
      age: 34
    },
    {
      name: "John35",
      age: 35
    },
    {
      name: "John36",
      age: 36
    }
  ];


  let source = [{
      name: "John30",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John31",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John32",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John33",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John34",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John35",
      age: "unknown"
    }, {
      name: "John36",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John37",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John38",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John39",
      age: "unknown"
    }
  ];

  const resolver = doc => {
    return new Promise(doc => {
      let clone = { ...doc
      };
      let found = refs.find(ref => {
        return ref.name === doc.name;
      });

      if (found) clone.age = found.age;
      return clone;
    });
  };

  let getRefs = (doc, refs) => {
    const promises = refs.map(r => {
      resolver(doc).then(result => {
        return result;
      });
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
  };


  let getCursorData = (cursor, refs, data) => {
    const promises = cursor.forEach(doc => {
      console.log("Getting cursor for " + doc.name);
      let clone = { ...doc
      };

      return getRefs(clone, refs).then(result => {
        console.log("Getting refs for " + clone.name);
        data.push(result);
      });
      return;
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
  };

  // Get data
  let data = [];
  await getCursorData(source, refs, data);

  console.log("Returned data: ");
  console.log(data);

  return data;
};

console.log("Begin");
getData().then(result => {
  console.log("End");
  console.log(result)
});
```

For some reason I'm not getting to the end of the code (`End` is not being printed). I suspect there is some position or missing return, but I'm stuck without finding the solution.

How can I make this code structure works as expected, as follows:

1. Iterate through source (my data that comes from database
2. For each register, apply reference changes (in the example change the
   `age`)
3. Return the data with the references fixed

The expected result of this code is to get the original data (`source`) with the available references fixed, using the current promise structures:

```
[
      name: "John30",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John31",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John32",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John33",
      age: 33
    },
    {
      name: "John34",
      age: 34
    },
    {
      name: "John35",
      age: 35
    }, {
      name: "John36",
      age: 36
    },
    {
      name: "John37",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John38",
      age: "unknown"
    },
    {
      name: "John39",
      age: "unknown"
    }
]
```

Comment: I see  `End` printed, though it's printed somewhere in the middle of all those `Getting refs...` lines. Perhaps the problem is you need to `await` or `then` your call to `getData`?

Comment: You're sure. Fixed the code to behave like my original error...

Comment: `new Promise()` takes as argument a function that gets a `resolve` (and `reject`) function as argument(s), not `doc`. That makes no sense.

Comment: What is missing explanation?

Comment: You're using `forEach` when you should be using `map` in `getCursorData` I believe. You'll make it to the end if you fix that, but you'll get a bunch of arrays of `undefined`. Is that your intended result with this?

Comment: If you want to chain promises you need to define the next promise in the `.then()` segment of the first promise

Comment: @Khauri, added results expectation. Can you please elaborate those fixes in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

here you go!

```js
const SimulatedDatabaseCall = new Promise(resolve => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  resolve([
   {
    name: 'John33',
    age: 33
   },
   {
    name: 'John34',
    age: 34
   },
   {
    name: 'John35',
    age: 35
   },
   {
    name: 'John36',
    age: 36
   }
  ]);
 }, 200);
});

let source = [
 {
  name: 'John30',
  age: 'unknown'
 },
 {
  name: 'John31',
  age: 'unknown'
 },
 {
  name: 'John32',
  age: 'unknown'
 },
 {
  name: 'John33',
  age: 'unknown'
 },
 {
  name: 'John34',
  age: 'unknown'
 },
 {
  name: 'John35',
  age: 'unknown'
 },
 {
  name: 'John36',
  age: 'unknown'
 },
 {
  name: 'John37',
  age: 'unknown'
 },
 {
  name: 'John38',
  age: 'unknown'
 },
 {
  name: 'John39',
  age: 'unknown'
 }
];

async function updateSource(source, SimulatedDatabaseCall) {
 await SimulatedDatabaseCall;
 SimulatedDatabaseCall.then(_database => {
  var sourceMap = source.map(_sourceOBJ => {
   return _sourceOBJ.name;
  });
  _database.forEach(_databaseOBJ => {
   var index = sourceMap.indexOf(_databaseOBJ.name);
   source[index].age = _databaseOBJ.age;
  });
 });

 return source;
}

updateSource(source, SimulatedDatabaseCall).then(_val => {
 console.log(_val);
});
```

Comment: A `SimulatedDatabaseCall` should be one per item, not one per all...

Comment: I mean this should work if adjusted to be once per item like Mendes said, but this won't help him learn what the issue with his original code was.  There isn't a problem with his original logic he just isn't getting the data into the promise objects properly.